# U.S. source for Alfine 11 oil for oil changes?

Tags: shimano, maintenance, internally-geared-hub, lubricant, alfine

Yesterday I changed the oil in my Alfine 11-speed hub. I bought the 50ml bottle of SG-S700 from an eBay seller in Florida, the last one in the site's search results originating from the United States. My neighborhood bike shops here in The Bronx and my usual online stores were all backordered. A local outfit that only builds belt-drive bikes doesn't have it for sale.

At this point, all I can see on eBay are vendors from the U.K. and Germany, where I'd pay more to ship a 50ml bottle than the retail cost of the oil itself.

American Alfine 11 owners who've done your own maintenance recently: Where did you find the oil?

Was it always this scarce in the States? This initially struck me as an effect of the COVID supply chain issues that walloped the bike industry. But I suspect the simple answer is there's still not enough demand for internal geared hubs in the U.S. to make the oil marketable here.

Regardless, since the cleaning/flushing step and the "add fresh oil" step used up the whole 50ml bottle, I'm thinking about where to buy next year's.

Comment: Some people use Rolhoff oil. It's a little bit cheaper and the kit is a bit more convenient.